# How to display loader before loading a PHP file into a DIV using ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My jQuery code:

```
function sendAJAX(){
    $('[data-append="sb-new-user"]').load("/assets/templates/sidebaraddons/new_users.php");
}; 

$(document).ready(function(){
    sendAJAX();
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="sb-new-user" data-append="sb-new-user">
</div>
```

In the end, what the .load() part loads into the div shall be shown, but before that, it shall show a loader that disappears after the .load() was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loading image in your HTML and hide it initially.

In your "sendAJAX" function, before calling "load" method, display the loading image by calling jquery method "show" or by setting css property or by adding a css class name.

Use the below  syntax for jquery load method :

```
$('[data-append="sb-new-user"]').load("/assets/templates/sidebaraddons/new_users.php", function() {
  //ITS A COMPLETE CALLBACK FUNCTION
  //HIDE THE LOADING IMAGE HERE
});
```

Documentation link is here: http://api.jquery.com/load/